# Best Approach to work with count down timer in background

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager

I am working on an application where I have to display the count down timer.Now I want to update the count down timer even when my application is in background.To achieve this what will be the best approach, workmanager or foreground service?

Comment: `ForegroundService`.

Comment: Any Specific reason?